# Finding argument of a bulky complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

If $$\mathcal{Z} = \frac{(2\sqrt3 + 2i)^8}{(1-i)^6} + \frac{(1-i)^6}{(2\sqrt3 - 2i)^8}$$

what is the argument of $\mathcal{Z}$?

considering the first term as ${Z}$ the other term becomes $\frac{1}{\overline{Z}}$. Is there any logic I could apply or any general method that may be there for these sort of problems , without actually expanding the whole thing ?

Comment: I would use polar form to evaluate $(2\sqrt3+2i)^8$ etc.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I tried that and I'm getting the argument of both parts as $\frac{17\pi}{6}$ , for the total argument , do I just sum them ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints (for a maybe simple evaluation):** $$(2\sqrt 3 +2i) =2(\sqrt 3 + i) $$ $$= 4\left[\frac{\sqrt 3}2 +\frac{i} 2\right]=4e^{\frac{\pi i}6} \tag 1$$

Similarly, $$(2\sqrt 3 - 2i) =4\left[\frac{\sqrt 3}2-\frac{i}{2}\right] $$ $$= 4e^{-\frac{\pi i} 6} \tag 2$$

And, $$(1-i)=\sqrt 2\left[\frac1{\sqrt 2}-\frac{i}{\sqrt 2}\right]$$ $$= \sqrt 2e^{-\frac{\pi i} 4}\tag 3$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
Let $x=2(3^{1/2}+i)$, $w=\bar{x}=\frac{16}{x}$, $y=(1-i)$ then $x^3=64i$, $w^3=-64i$, $y^2=-2i$.